# How to fix application has stopped in android app when clicking another button inside main activity?

Tags: java, android, button

I have an app that when logged in by user the user redirects to main activity which had his personal details displayed and had two buttons to click: dashboard button redirected to his dashboard manager settings and a button log out. When logged in all is working fine showing his personal details and when I clicked dashboard button for his dashboard settings the app is unfortunately stopped. It said errors in my log cat which I can't fix with my own. I am new to Android. I searched and tried threads here in SO that has same problems with me but still can not be solved. Anybody with a great heart can help me to solve this? It's been quiet a week I'm stuck on this.

note* my **dashboard button** is calling another layout that contains two buttons

This is my **main activity java** :

```
package com.myapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import library.JSONParser;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProfileView extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private Button bLogout, backdashboard;
private TextView tvusername, tvfullname;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// Profile json object
JSONArray user;
JSONObject display;

//String name for my sharedpref extras
String ngalan;

// Profile JSON url
private static final String PROFILE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/webservice/profile.php";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile);

    //setup textview
    tvusername=(TextView)(findViewById(R.id.tvusernamedisplay));
    tvfullname=(TextView)(findViewById(R.id.tvfullname));

    //settup buttons
    backdashboard=(Button)(findViewById(R.id.backdashboard));
    bLogout=(Button)(findViewById(R.id.blogout));


    //button listener

    backdashboard.setOnClickListener(this);
    bLogout.setOnClickListener(this);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras.containsKey("username")) {
        ngalan = extras.getString("username");
     // Loading Profile in Background Thread
        new LoadProfile().execute();
    }


}

@Override
public void onClick(View args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (args.getId()) {
    case R.id.backdashboard:
    Intent r = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
    startActivity(r);
    finish();
    break;
    case R.id.blogout:
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Logout")
    .setMessage("Would you like to logout?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // logout
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ProfileView.this, LoginActivity.class);
            myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);// clear back stack
            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // user doesn't want to logout
        }
     })
     .show();

    default:
    break;
    }
}

class LoadProfile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProfileView.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Profile ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting Profile JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        String json = null;


        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", ngalan));

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(PROFILE_URL);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            json = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

            Log.i("Profile JSON: ", json.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
        super.onPostExecute(json);
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        try
        {
        display = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray user = display.getJSONArray("user");
        JSONObject jb= user.getJSONObject(0);
        String idnum = jb.getString("username");
        String fulname = jb.getString("lastname");


        // displaying all data in textview

        tvusername.setText(idnum );
        tvfullname.setText(fulname);

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
    }
```

This is my **Dashboard activity java** another activity calls when dashboard button is clicked...

```
package com.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Dashboard extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private Button view, manage, logout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
    initialise();


}

private void initialise() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //settup buttons

    manage=(Button)(findViewById(R.id.bManage));
    view=(Button)(findViewById(R.id.bView));

    logout=(Button)(findViewById(R.id.blogout));

    //button listener

    manage.setOnClickListener(this);
    view.setOnClickListener(this);
    logout.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getId()) {
    case R.id.bManage:
    Intent r = new Intent(this, Manage.class);
    startActivity(r);
    finish();
    break;
    case R.id.bView:
    Intent l = new Intent(this, View.class);
    startActivity(l);
    finish();
    break;
    case R.id.blogout:
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Logout")
        .setMessage("Would you like to logout?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                // logout
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, LoginActivity.class);
                myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);// clear back stack
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            }
         })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                // user doesn't want to logout
            }
         })
         .show();
    default:
    break;
    }
}
```

}

This is my **log cat error** message"

```
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.Dashboard}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please help me guys :(

**This is the full logcat message:**

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.Dashboard}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at com.myapp.Dashboard.onCreate(Dashboard.java:27)
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: First guess?? one of the findViewById()'s failed, returning null. Please check your XML, and post the **full** stacktrace, especially the line number where it failed.

Comment: @androidbeginner08 : other lines of Logcat might be useful to help , for NPE you should trace your code to find out which line cause error.

Comment: @Arash see my full logcat above

Comment: @Jitsu see my posted full logcat above

Comment: indicate line `08-23 18:59:36.949: E/AndroidRuntime(900):  at com.myapp.Dashboard.onCreate(Dashboard.java:27)`

Comment: aka Line 27 in Dashboard.java

Answer (score 0):

I guess that NPE occurs in this line: `grade.setOnClickListener(this);`
You don't initialize this variable anywhere.

Comment: sorry i mistype the variavle supposedly thats manage.set.setOnClickListener(this); i already edited it but still the problem is at ease

Comment: I mean the line from the `Dashboard.java`